# Preventing duplicate entry messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, class, cocoa

I have two classes that are pretty much identical but one is made for OS X and the other one is made for iOS. Then I have a header file like this:

```
#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
#import "ClassForOSX.h"
#else
#import "ClassForIOS.h"
#endif
```

The problem is because both classes are included in the project, xcode compiles both and I have a lot of duplicate entries on the errors, because methods have the same name on both classes.

Is there a way to prevent a class from compiling, even if it is included on the project, unless the class is meant for the target?

Yes I know I can include/exclude classes from targets but I am dealing with hundreds of classes in both sides and multiple targets and that would generate a lot of include/exclude operations that will eventually go wrong. I was wondering if there is some solution in code that can just allow a class to compile if the target is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use targets is best for your case. But You can do it in code

note add or remove `__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` at Preprocessor Macros at target->Build Settings

ClassForIOS.h file

```
#ifndef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassForIOS : NSObject

// interface

@end

#endif
```

ClassForIOS.m file

```
#ifndef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED

#import "ClassForIOS.h"

@implementation ClassForIOS

// implementation code

@end

#endif
```

ClassForOSX.h file

```
#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ClassForOSX : NSObject

// interface

@end

#endif
```

ClassForOSX.m file

```
#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED

#import "ClassForOSX.h"

@implementation ClassForOSX

// implementation code

@end

#endif
```

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is important: "Using targets is best for your case".  This is what targets are for.  Have one target for OS X, one target for iOS, add the appropriate source files to each.  If that does not work for some reason, then and only then, file a bug and follow the rest of the solution given above.  Your reason for not using targets makes no sense to me; maintaining #ifdefs in all source files is just as complex and error-prone as using targets, and in both cases, if you do it incorrectly you will get a build error, so maintaining the targets correctly is easy.